# The method 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType' was called on null fluro

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to initialize fluro navigation for my app, but I always get this issue 
The method 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType' was called on null. and this
The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 4553):   MaterialApp
 here is my main :

```
void main() {
  Application.router = Router();
  Application.configureRoutes();
  runApp(App());
}
```

and my my App widget :

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

    class _AppState extends State<App> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'myApp',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
          theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 0.9))),
          onGenerateRoute: Application.router.generator,
        );
      }
    }
```

and use these classes to configure fluro:

```
class Application {
  static Router router;

  static void configureRoutes() {
    router.notFoundHandler = Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, List<dynamic>> params) {
      print("ROUTE WAS NOT FOUND !!!");
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("ROUTE WAS NOT FOUND !!!"),
        ),
      );
    });
    router.define(Routes.root,
        handler: Handlers.rootHandler, transitionType: TransitionType.native);
  }
}
```

and this for routes :

```
class Routes {
  static String root = "/";
}
```

and this for handlers:

```
class Handlers {
  static Handler rootHandler = Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, List<dynamic>> params) {
      return Container(color: Colors.blue,);
    },
  );
}
```

I have no idea where this comes from I tried to add key for MaterialApp but in vain.

any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue. According to https://github.com/theyakka/fluro/issues/154

`transitionType: TransitionType.native`

This part seems to be the cause. In my case, it works if I removed this part.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue, but in my case, I really needed to use the `transitionType` because I wanted it as `transitionType: TransitionType.nativeModal`.

My solution to make it work was simply to downgrade fluro to version `1.5.1`.